# Flutter GeoFire SetLocation Hangs and is Not Working

Tags: flutter, geofire

I have initialised Geofire and called SetLocation but the data does not appear in realitime database. I noticed that the execution of the code stops when the setLocation method is called but without any error.

Below is the code;

```
Geofire.initialize("availableDrivers");
await Geofire.setLocation(currentFirebaseUser!.uid, currentPosition!.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);
```

I have also applied the rules in the realtime database.

In the Debug Console in VS Code, I get the following 2 lines;

I/TAG     ( 8574): GeoFire.start
I/TAG     ( 8574): setLocation

I changed the default location for my databse and have to use databaseURL when making calls to the realtime database, I do not know if this is relevant.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I got the error below when running the app for the first time on an emulator. I did not notice it on the device I was using before because the app was already installed on the device.

> Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://delivery-swag-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app

I had the realtime database in a location that was not the default. I then migrated my app to a different project with the default location setup.

There might be a setting in Flutter Geofire to set the Database URL, but I could not find it, so I opted to migrate the project.